# How can I create a matlab multi-line edit box in Guide?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, matlab-guide

I am fairly new to Matlab and I am using GUIDE to create a GUI. I am looking to make a GUI that I can enter an item name and description and other stuff and then upon submit, they will be submitted into database.

My question is how to make a Description box , like where I put the item description. I did try the edit box but it is a single line object.

Thank you

Comment: here is an example you might find useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910287/display-window-for-text-files/7932849#7932849

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for the [properties of uicontrols](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol_props.html#bqxoinq). You can set the `Max` and `Min` properties of an edit box. I know it seems crazy, but if `Max - Min > 1`, the edit box will accept multiline input; if `Max - Min <= 1`, it is single line only. Otherwise, the `Max` and `Min` properties have no effect on edit box controls.

Another option would be to have separate input methods for the name, description and other stuff that you want your users to enter via the GUI. Depending on your application, that might make for a cleaner GUI design.

Comment: Thanks so much, didn't find that myself so far and wondered why the box displayed as multiline... Worked like a charm!